# why this std::bind fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

What is the fault of this bind operation with visual studio 2013 for error C3867 ?

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m1, m2;
    std::vector<std::map<int, int> *> pM;

    std::for_each(pM.begin(), pM.end(), 
        std::bind(std::map<int, int>::erase , 1));
}
```

Comment: For one thing, member functions do not decay into member function pointers. For another, `std::map::erase` is overloaded.

Comment: [What does the error say?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE)

Comment: SAYING couldn't deduce template parameter

Comment: Did you really mean `1`? Where is your dereference of the vector members? It seems obvious that this won't work. Explain your specific issue better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete each map's element (which key is 1)  in the vector. Here is a sample.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m1 {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}}, m2 {{2,3},{1,5},{8,9}};

    std::vector<std::map<int, int> *> pM {&m1,&m2};

    size_t(std::map<int,int>::*pf)(const int& key)=&std::map<int,int>::erase;//note this line.

    std::for_each(pM.begin(), pM.end(),std::bind(pf,_1,1));//note this line

    for(auto& ele:m1)
    {
        cout<<ele.first<<","<<ele.second<<endl;
    }
    for(auto& ele:m2)
    {
        cout<<ele.first<<","<<ele.second<<endl;
    }
}
```

**As chris says:**

> For one thing, member functions do not decay into member function
>   pointers. For another, std::map::erase is overloaded.

We must use `&` to get member function pointer,and must tell compiler which overload function you want to choice.
So write code like this:

```
size_t(std::map<int,int>::*pf)(const int& key)=&std::map<int,int>::erase;
```

**And further：**

```
std::bind(pf,_1,1)
```

member function need object as its implicit first parameter, `_1` do this work.The last parameter `1` is int as the key pass to map erase member function.

Comment: a bit simplified version for picking the right overload is `std::mem_fun<size_t>(&std::map<int, int>::erase)`. `mem_fun` is marked as deprecated but as usual with C++ won't be removed. The newer `std::mem_fn` doesn't work - I assume it's because variadic template deduction functions a bit differently.

Comment: @klaustriendl yes,i think so.